# Debootstrap Ubuntu over NFS leads to mknod I/O error

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, pxe-boot

I'm trying to prepare an Ubuntu environment for a diskless machine that will PXE boot and mount an NFS share as it's root. I've currently got another Ubuntu machine mounting the NFS share and I'm trying to debootstrap into it, but it has trouble creating devices over NFS:

```
root@kimiko:~# mount | grep Seiuchi
192.168.0.203:/mnt/user/Seiuchi on /mnt type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.0.203)
root@kimiko:~# debootstrap --arch i386 maverick /mnt http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
mknod: `/mnt/test-dev-null': Input/output error
E: Cannot install into target '/mnt' mounted with noexec or nodev
```

My NFS rule on the unRAID server is `192.168.0.201/32(rw,no_root_squash,sync)`. I don't have the `noexec` or `nodev` options set. I've not got much experience with NFS, so I'm probably missing something basic in the way I'm sharing this, but my attempts at Googling for an answer isn't really turning anything useful up.

Does anyone have suggestions on what I might have missed or maybe relevant docs?

**Edit:** Creating normal files (and directories) works just fine, I just can't create devices...

```
root@kimiko:/mnt# mkdir foo
root@kimiko:/mnt# cd foo
root@kimiko:/mnt/foo# touch bar
root@kimiko:/mnt/foo# mknod quux c 4 64
mknod: `quux': Input/output error
root@kimiko:/mnt/foo# ls
bar
```

Comment: Have you tried `touch /mnt/test` to see if you can create *any* file on the NFS mount?

Comment: Yeah, I can create normal files no problem, but it just won't let me create devices... see edit to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like unRAID doesn't have mknod support in its filesystem driver right now, which seems like the root of my problem. If anyone wants to follow this issue, I've created [this thread over in the unRAID forums](http://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?topic=11134).